# How can I upgrade the dart sdk from flutter 1.22.4 stable channel?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter 1.22.4 stable channel for a project. In this sdk dart 2.10.0 sdk is integrated. Now i want to upgrade the dart sdk to 2.12.0. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to flutter 2.0, the dart version switches to 2.12. Here is [How To Upgrade Your Mobile App to Flutter 2.0+](https://www.objectivity.co.uk/blog/how-to-upgrade-mobile-app-flutter-2-0/) and [How to Migrate Your Mobile App to Flutter 2.0](https://radixweb.com/blog/migrate-your-mobile-app-to-flutter-2)

Check out [Flutter Version History | Brief Details Of Flutter Version List](https://www.angularminds.com/blog/article/flutter-versions-releases-and-features.html) for more information